# R Horizontal Stacked ggvis Barplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, ggvis

Using this small dataset:

```
df <- structure(list(colour = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Black", 
"White"), class = "factor"), variable = c("A", "A", "B", "B"), 
    value = c(1, 2, 0.74, 0.85)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .Names = c("colour", 
"variable", "value"), class = "data.frame")
```

I can easily create a vertical stacked barplot with `ggvis`

```
library(ggvis)
df %>%
  ggvis(x=~variable, y=~value, fill=~colour) %>%
  group_by(colour) %>%
  layer_bars()
```

[image]

But I cannot figure out how to have a horizontal stacked barplot.  I think I am somehow supposed to use `layer_rects` but the best I could get so far was just one group plotted.

```
df %>%
  ggvis(x =~value, y=~variable, fill =~ colour) %>%
  group_by(colour) %>%
  layer_rects(x2 = 0, height = band())
```

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `layer_bars()` stacks automatically, `layer_rects()` doesn't.  You need to be explicit about the stacks using `compute_stack()`.

```
df %>%
  ggvis(y = ~variable, fill = ~colour) %>%
  compute_stack(stack_var = ~value, group_var = ~variable) %>% 
  layer_rects(x = ~stack_lwr_, x2 = ~stack_upr_, height = band())
```

Which gives:

[image]

---

**Note:** Looking at this code, you might wonder where the `stack_lwr_` and `stack_upr_` arguments come from. Take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/rstudio/ggvis/blob/master/R/compute_stack.R) to see how it works under the hood

Comment: Excellent, exactly what I needed.  Thanks